# Count From Time Range In Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that count the total number of users registered in our service per day, per hour. My problem is that i want to appear the hour in range style. You can see below:

Query:

```
    SELECT
    case
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 0 then 'Sunday'
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 1 then 'Monday'
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 2 then 'Tuesday'
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 3 then 'Wednesday'
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 4 then 'Thursday'
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 5 then 'Friday'
      when extract(dow from us.created::timestamp) = 6 then 'Saturday'
      end as wday,
    extract(hour from us.created::timestamp)  as whour,
    count(us.id)
  FROM users us
  GROUP BY wday,whour order by wday, whour
```

Query Result:

```
wday whour count
Friday 0 364
Friday 1 156
Friday 2 79
Friday 3 39
Friday 4 55
Friday 5 32 ....
```

I want to count and appear the results in this format:

```
wday whour count
Friday 0-1 364
Friday 1-2 156
Friday 2-3 79
Friday 3-4 39
Friday 4-5 55
Friday 5-6 32 ....
```

How can i do this?

Comment: try `select to_char(now(),'Day')` - no need for those `CASE`

Comment: your hours are sequential or can have gaps?

Comment: Hours are sequential. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try smth like :

```
WITH a as (
   SELECT 
    to_char(us.created::timestamp,'Day') as wday,
    extract(hour from us.created::timestamp)  as whour,
    count(us.id)
  FROM users us
  GROUP BY wday,whour
)
select 
  wday
, coalesce(whour,'-',lead(whour) over (partition by wday order by whour)) whour
, count
from a
 order by wday, whour
```

here's the logic sample:

```
t=# with v(i,e) as (
  values
  ('Friday',2),('Friday',3),('Saturday',4),('Saturday',5),('Saturday',6),('Friday',4),('Friday',5),('Friday',0),('Friday',1)
)
select i,e,concat(e,'-',lead(e) over (partition by i order by e))
from v;
    i     | e | concat
----------+---+--------
 Friday   | 0 | 0-1
 Friday   | 1 | 1-2
 Friday   | 2 | 2-3
 Friday   | 3 | 3-4
 Friday   | 4 | 4-5
 Friday   | 5 | 5-
 Saturday | 4 | 4-5
 Saturday | 5 | 5-6
 Saturday | 6 | 6-
(9 rows)
```

Comment: First, it didn't let me use the whour in group by so i removed it from group by nut now in the whour i have something like this: 11-11, 12-12, 13-13.. There is no 11-12, 12-13..

Comment: refactored - try now. btw when you give table structure and provide some data sample - answers have less errors

Comment: The db created field is just a timestamp as you understand. So nothing funky there.